# GitHub CLI "gh repo clone <username>/<repo-name>" keeps requesting username/password even though I am already authenticated

Tags: linux, github, github-cli

I am trying to clone a repository from my GitHub account. I have logged into my account using:

```
> gh auth login --with-token < gh-token.txt

> gh --version
gh version 2.4.0+dfsg1 (2022-03-23 Ubuntu 2.4.0+dfsg1-2)
https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/latest

> gh auth status
github.com
  ✓ Logged in to github.com as mogur (/home/jonathon/.config/gh/hosts.yml)
  ✓ Git operations for github.com configured to use https protocol.
  ✓ Token: *******************
```

Everything seems fine until I try and clone a repository.

```
> gh repo clone mogur/alpha
Cloning into 'alpha'...
Username for 'https://github.com': mogur   
Password for 'https://mogur@github.com': **************
gh auth git-credential: "erase" operation not supported
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-
remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/mogur/alpha.git/'
exit status 128
```

I can't seem to find any documentation that would explain these results. I'm confused as to why I am being asked for a username and password.

I followed the instructions from "https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_clone" and was expecting:

Cloning a repository:

```
~/Projects$ gh repo clone cli/cli
Cloning into 'cli'...
~/Projects$ cd cli
~/Projects/cli$
```

I also tried:

```
~/Projects/my-project$ gh repo clone https://github.com/cli/cli
Cloning into 'cli'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 99, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (99/99), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (76/76), done.
remote: Total 21160 (delta 49), reused 35 (delta 18), pack-reused 21061
Receiving objects: 100% (21160/21160), 57.93 MiB | 10.82 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (16051/16051), done.
```

Answer (score 1):

First, check your `gh version` since this error message, reported in [`cli/cli` issue 3891](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/3891) is supposed to be fixed with [PR 6805](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/6805) for `gh` v2.21.2 in January 2023.

Second, the [latest `gh` release 2.24.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.24.0) introduced:

> ### Option to store `gh` access token in system encrypted storage
>
> The `gh auth login` and `gh auth refresh` commands gained the new `--secure-storage` flag.
> In this mode, the access token that GitHub CLI uses for GitHub API requests will now be stored in the system keyring instead of in the plain text config file.
>
> To migrate as an existing GitHub CLI user, re-authenticate like so:
>
> ```
> gh auth refresh --secure-storage -h github.com
> ```
>
> Depending on your system, you could get an interactive prompt to allow the CLI tool to access the system keyring. The systems that are supported are:
>
> - Keychain on macOS
> - GNOME Keyring on Linux (Secret Service dbus interface)
> - Wincred on Windows

Your error message could be a side effect of this new (opt-in) option.

Comment: That seems to have fixed it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mogur Well done. What step did you do to fix it? Using the new secure storage?